# Hints for solving $\tan(x) = 1 - 2\sin(x)$ for the domain of $[0, \pi/4]$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $$\tan(x) = 1 - 2\sin(x)$$ for the domain of $[0, \pi/4].$

Thanks! And please just point me to some direction without the answer.

I actually had tried few trig identities and managed to rewrite this as a 4th degree polynomial, but then I did not know how to solve the 4th degree polynomial so I just used my calculator to find the roots of the polynomial, and plugged the roots into arcsin.

Comment: What have you done? Tried multiplying by $\cos x$, for example?

Comment: Hint: multiply with $\cos(x)$. Then add $1$ to both sides of the equation. Rewrite it as an equation for $z=\sin(x)-\cos(x)$.

Comment: I actually had tried few trig identities and managed to rewrite this as a 4th degree polynomial, but then I did not know how to solve the 4th degree polynomial so I just used my calculator to find the roots of the polynomial, and plugged the roots into arcsin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider that you look for the zero(s) of function
$$f(x)=\tan(x) + 2\sin(x)-1$$
By inspection, $f(0)=-1$ and $f\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)=\sqrt{2}$. On the other side, the derivative is positive in the whole range. So, the solution is unique.

Assuming that you do not know the value of the trigonometric functions of $\frac{\pi }{8}$, we cannot bound more. But $\frac{\pi }{4}$ is quite small; so, may be, a very truncated Taylor series will provide a very simple approximation.

If you want to polish it, use Newton method.

Comment: Thanks! But this question was post accidentally. I typed it out but thought I didn't click the post button. So I'm deleting it.

Comment: Actually I like your answer and appreciate your help. So I'll leave this question here. Thanks again!